# How do I find Y-Intercept with X1, X2, Y1, Y2

Tags: math, vbscript, equation

I am working on a project for my seventh grade math class and I was wondering how would I calculate the Y-Intercept of a graph with two points knowing the position of the two points.
Here is what I have:

```
Option Explicit
Dim X1, X2, Y1, Y2, Y, X, S
X1=InputBox("Enter X1")
Y1=InputBox("Enter Y1")
X2=InputBox("Enter X2")
Y2=InputBox("Enter Y2")
X=X2-X1
Y=Y2-Y1
S=Y/X
MsgBox("The slope of [" & X1 & "," & Y1 & "] and [" & X2 & "," & Y2 & "] is " & S)
MsgBox("Equation: (" & Y2 & "-" & Y1 & ") / (" & X2 & "-" & X1 & ") = " & S)
```

I don't know how to compute (X1, Y1) and (X2, Y2) into the Y-Intercept.

Comment: Given the equation `y = m*x + b`, where `m` is the slope and `b` is the y-intercept, you already have `y`, `m`, and `x` (just plug in `X1, Y1`), so you can solve for `b`.

Answer (score 3):

First step is to find the slope.  Which it looks like you're doing with S = Y/X.

After that it is easy:

y-intercept = Y1 - S*X1

Answer (score 0):

The line passing through a point `(X1,Y1)` with slope `S` is

```
y(x) = Y1 + S*(x-X1)
```

The line passing through two points `(X1,Y1)` and `(X2,Y2)` is

```
y(x) = Y1 + (Y2-Y1)*(x-X1)/(X2-X1)
```

The line crosses the y-axis at

```
Y0 = (X2*Y1-X1*Y2)/(X2-X1)
```

Alternate form of the line on the `xy` plane is

```
(X2-X1)*y - (Y2-Y1)*x = X2*Y1-X1*Y2 = constant
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this

```
p1 = InputBox("Enter X1,Y1","Y Intercept")
p2 = InputBox("Enter X2,Y2","Y Intercept")
x1 = Left(p1,InStr(p1,",") -  1)
y1 = Replace(p1,x1 & ",","")
x2 = Left(p2,InStr(p2,",") -  1)
y2 = Replace(p2,x2 & ",","")
MsgBox "Y Intercept = " & y2 - (((y2-y1)/(x2-x1)) * x2)
```